# kotlin get image name from imageview

Tags: xml, kotlin

I am using kotlin, I want to get image name displayed in xml `imageview`.

I want to get it when display by `srcCompat` and background and set the name of image to the `TextView`.

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageview"
android:background="@drawable/img900"
tools:srcCompat="@drawable/img900"/>

<TextView
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imagename"/>
```

Comment: What you mean `"name of image"`?

Comment: i mean a source name of image choosed from gallery and put it in imageview